# Ionic/Cordova File Transfer "forgets" path of earlier picked images from gallery

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, file-transfer

**Info:** Ionic/Cordova application, File Transfer Plugin (ngCordova), Tested on Android.

I need user can pick multiple images from either camera or gallery. When I use images from camera, everything works perfectly. But when using *more than one* image from gallery, it only takes the newest picked image.

**Hypothetical scenario:** 
I pick the first image from gallery, which gives me longpath/modified.jpg?12345678. I put this in imgArr array. Then I pick the second image from gallery, which gives me longpath/modified.jpg?99999, and put this into the next field of the array. 
When looping and sending these to server, it only sends *the image of* longpath/modified.jpg?99999 TWICE, but with the name of both.

The array remembers these paths correctly, since I've alerted them right before the transfer.

This code is within a loop. **i** is a counter.

```
var idforitem = data;
                      var options = {
                             fileKey: "file",
                             fileName: imgArr[i].substr(imgArr[i].lastIndexOf('/') + 1), 
                             chunkedMode: false,
                             mimeType: "image/jpeg",
                            params : {'id':idforitem}
                         };

 $cordovaFileTransfer.upload("http://url/imgadd",imgArr[i], options).then(function(result) {

alert(result.response);


                      }, function(err) {
                         alert("Error");
                      }
                     );
```

Can anyone help me out with this one? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda solved it by adding this:

```
 $cordovaFileTransfer.download(imageURI, cordova.file.dataDirectory + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1) + ".jpg", {}, true).then(
                          function(fileEntry)
                          {
                             imgArr[0] = fileEntry.nativeURL;
                              img1=true;
                          },
                          function (error)
                          {
                              console.log(error);
                          }
                      );
```

Keeping the question open, since this doesn't seem like the best solution.